# Ubuntu Buildozer JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to run buildozer 
First step `buildozer init` is ok 
When I did: `buildozer -v android debug` it sent me error:

`JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin`
`Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation.`

Please help me. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `JAVA_HOME` to the following path:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

`JAVA_HOME` should point to the root of the java installation folder, but in your case it points to the nested `bin` folder inside of java installation directory.

Java installation directory has a known structure, and applications use path to the installation root (set to `JAVA_HOME`) to build final absolute path to the java utilites and binary files.

Comment: my bashrc file:
  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
  export PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH
   export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
   export PATH="$PATH:/opt/netbeans/bin/"
   export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/

is that true?

Comment: I add /jre: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre. And it work, thanks

Comment: @KataVankee glad I helped you :)